# Can't access object properties even though I can see they exist

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't access any of the object properties, keep getting undefined.

I have tried

```
console.log(JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user.userId));
```

and

```
console.log(JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user[0].userId));
```

When I do

```
console.log(JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user.userId));
```

I get

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"
```

When I just do

```
 console.log(JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user));
```

I get the object and I can see the properties. It's just that whenever I try to access them I get `undefined`.

Comment: You will have to post the content of the object too. But my guess would be a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I just do console.log(JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user)); I get the object and I can see the properties.

This means that `this.$store.state.user` contains JSON string which describes the `user` object.

Thus `JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user.userId)` is incorrect. In this case you are trying to get property `userId` from string, getting `undefined` and `JSON.parse` function fails on the first symbol, which is `'u'`.

You should use `JSON.parse(this.$store.state.user).userId` instead.

Comment: You're welcome. I appreciate, If you mark my answer as long as it helped